# How to transfer a large video (> 2 GB) from iPhone to a PC?

Tags: iphone, itunes, video, pc

I have installed iTunes on my PC.
However, when I click Photos → Sync Photos,
it says

> You can choose which photos from your computer are copied to your iPhone.
>   It seems that it copies photos from the computer to the iPhone, but not the other way around.

**Question:**
How do I transfer a large video (> 2 GB) from an iPhone to a PC?

Comment: There are many support articles written by Apple, and other 3rd parties, on how to transfer files/photos from an iPhone to a PC.  Have you tried any of them?

Comment: Did you try some storage app like Google Drive? You can upload up to 15GB and download later on your PC

Answer (score 1):

You can use the program [iExplorer](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/). It is free, and you can download it to view files on your iDevice. Simply plug in your phone, open iExplorer, and then on the sidebar, select Photos -> Recorded Videos.

[image: Sidebar]

Answer (score 1):

A method which works for me is to use Google Photos and a WiFi network.

I install Google Photos on my iPhone.
When the iPhone is connected to a WiFi network,
the video automatically gets uploaded to Google Photos.

After the video is uploaded and processed,
I can simply download it from Google Photos onto my PC.

The shortcoming of this method is that it can be slow,
and it can drain my iPhone battery.
For example,
it may take 1 hour to upload and process a 5 GB video to Google Photos,
though it takes only about 5 minutes to download.

Answer (score 0):

I have had same problems with my iPhones (5s and 7).  I found that my problem was my phone was just too full, and it was causing phone to act "buggy" and slow.  I was able to transfer small pics but videos were a nightmare, and often the iPhone would become unrecognized after one video transfer, or even before.  Then I would have to unplug/replug my phone in to pc and try again.

I found that a newer lightning cable (the one with my 7 not my 5s) helped a little bit.

But what really made the difference for me was clearing off several GB of space on my phone (delete or offload some apps and stuff like that, which was also very difficult to do while phone memory was low).

Once I had more free space on my phone than the size of the largest video I had, then photo/video transfer from iPhone to Windows pc was a piece of cake again.

I guess just like with Windows PC's, you should always try to keep a good chunk of free space for it to work with.  I wish I could set a warning on my iPhone, when I only have a couple GB of free space left, so I can make it a priority to move/backup my pics BEFORE phone acts flaky.

And I really wish I could make the iphone pause taking video (or at least give me a warning), before it records onto all the free space left on my phone!  It has happened many times as I was recording, that the video stopped, but only because there was no space left on the phone.  That seems like it would be great, except that then the phone is slow and buggy and it's really hard to transfer pics/videos off to regain that free space needed!